# Can a YACC parse an ambiguous grammar

Tags: compilers, parsers

I found a question while studying compilers :-

Given a grammar E->E+E/E×E/number

The above grammar is fed to a YACC with semantic rules for parsing. What will be the action of the YACC.

1) it detects recursion and eliminates recursion.

2) it detects RR conflict and resolves

3) it detects SR conflict and resolves in favour of Shift over Reduce action

4) it detects SR conflict and resolves in favour of reduce over shift action

The answer given is option 3. But I have read that LALR parser cannot parse ambiguous grammar, while the above grammar is ambiguous.

A) So how can YACC(which is a LALR parser) parse the given grammar?

B) What about other ambiguous grammar, I.e. can YACC parse all the ambiguous grammars?

Comment: Why don't you feed this grammar to YACC and see what happens?

Comment: This seems to be a question about the behaviour of a specific piece of software (YACC), rather than a question about the principles of computer science.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  but can the YACC parse any given ambiguous grammar? i know it can resolve the SR and RR conflicts but can it parse any given ambiguous grammar? and if it is ambiguous and it is parsed, is the resulted parse tree the same as the language of the grammar?

Comment: Once again, I suggest trying it out and see what happens.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus it does work with this grammar but I'm asking about all the ambiguous grammars, i can't check to see if it's gonna work with all the ambiguous grammars

Comment: I don't see that question listed in your post above.  Your question above is "So how can YACC parse the given grammar?"  If you really meant to ask "Can YACC parse all ambiguous grammars?", please edit the question to make sure that is clear.  (However, I'm not sure that the capabilities of a specific software tool are on-topic here.  Perhaps you ask on a support mailing list for YACC.  This question is about computer science.)

Comment: Also, I'm confused.  Are you using two accounts?  (John P and Atul Kumar)  Or is this two different people?  If you have a different question, I suggest posting it separately.  If you've created two accounts, you might want to [merge them](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49628199/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/90163/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W. I have only one account with username Atul Kumar. John P is a different user.

Comment: If you have the Dragon Book, there is a section on parsing ambiguous grammars with yacc, and that question comes directly from that section. Otherwise, there are lots of internet resources, including for example https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/using_rule_yaccprg.htm Your favourite search engine will find more for you.